# Integrate Tweeter tweets in Listview of Android by API 1.1 App

Tags: android, listview, twitter

I am facing issue regarding integrating tweets in Android listview but it is hard for me to implement or being beginner in android develomnet.
I follow this link -> http://therockncoder.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-twitter-api-11-app.html

But during compilation i got some error and hard to remove and don't know whether it will work or not .
Please help

Logcat details

```
12-09 18:50:51.762: E/Trace(1786): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-09 18:50:51.762: W/Trace(1786): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-09 18:50:51.762: W/Trace(1786): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-09 18:50:51.762: W/Trace(1786): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-09 18:50:52.321: W/Trace(1786): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-09 18:50:52.321: W/Trace(1786): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-09 18:50:52.331: D/AndroidRuntime(1786): Shutting down VM
12-09 18:50:52.331: W/dalvikvm(1786): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d17908)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.eample.twitter_tutorial/com.eample.twitter_tutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.eample.twitter_tutorial.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.eample.twitter_tutorial-2.apk
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.eample.twitter_tutorial.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.eample.twitter_tutorial-2.apk
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
12-09 18:50:52.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1786):     ... 11 more
```

Here Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ListActivity activity;
    final static String ScreenName = "therockncoder";
    final static String LOG_TAG = "rnc";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = this;

        downloadTweets();
    }

    // download twitter timeline after first checking to see if there is a network connection
    public void downloadTweets() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadTwitterTask().execute(ScreenName);
        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "No network connection available.");
        }
    }

    // Uses an AsyncTask to download a Twitter user's timeline
    private class DownloadTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "my consumer key";
        final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "my consumer secret";
        final static String TwitterTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
        final static String TwitterStreamURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... screenNames) {
            String result = null;

            if (screenNames.length > 0) {
                result = getTwitterStream(screenNames[0]);
            }
            return result;
        }

        // onPostExecute convert the JSON results into a Twitter object (which is an Array list of tweets
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Twitter twits = jsonToTwitter(result);

            // lets write the results to the console as well
            for (Tweet tweet : twits) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, tweet.getText());
            }

            // send the tweets to the adapter for rendering
            ArrayAdapter<Tweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, twits);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        // converts a string of JSON data into a Twitter object
        private Twitter jsonToTwitter(String result) {
            Twitter twits = null;
            if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    twits = gson.fromJson(result, Twitter.class);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // just eat the exception
                }
            }
            return twits;
        }

        // convert a JSON authentication object into an Authenticated object
        private Authenticated jsonToAuthenticated(String rawAuthorization) {
            Authenticated auth = null;
            if (rawAuthorization != null && rawAuthorization.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    auth = gson.fromJson(rawAuthorization, Authenticated.class);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // just eat the exception
                }
            }
            return auth;
        }

        private String getResponseBody(HttpRequestBase request) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

                if (statusCode == 200) {

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    sb.append(reason);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            } catch (ClientProtocolException ex1) {
            } catch (IOException ex2) {
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String getTwitterStream(String screenName) {
            String results = null;

            // Step 1: Encode consumer key and secret
            try {
                // URL encode the consumer key and secret
                String urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
                String urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");

                // Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character, and the
                // encoded consumer secret
                String combined = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;

                // Base64 encode the string
                String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(combined.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

                // Step 2: Obtain a bearer token
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TwitterTokenURL);
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Encoded);
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
                String rawAuthorization = getResponseBody(httpPost);
                Authenticated auth = jsonToAuthenticated(rawAuthorization);

                // Applications should verify that the value associated with the
                // token_type key of the returned object is bearer
                if (auth != null && auth.token_type.equals("bearer")) {

                    // Step 3: Authenticate API requests with bearer token
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TwitterStreamURL + screenName);

                    // construct a normal HTTPS request and include an Authorization
                    // header with the value of Bearer <>
                    httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.access_token);
                    httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    // update the results with the body of the response
                    results = getResponseBody(httpGet);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex1) {
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this line by your own "Consumer Key (API Key)" and "Consumer Secret (API Secret)"

```
    final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "my consumer key";
    final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "my consumer secret";
```

to do so, go to https://apps.twitter.com and create your own App